# Is Richardson iteration algorithm backward stable?

Tags: algorithm, iteration, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

How do we analyze the numerical stability of [Richardson iteration algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Richardson_iteration)? Can we say it is  backward stable?

Comment: Wouldn't this question be a better fit for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The same question is already asked at Mathematics Stack Exchange:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567782/is-richardson-iteration-algorithm-backward-stable